# Streaming API to transfer FILES to online cloud storage

Tags: api, custom-object, files, streaming-api, pushtopic

Using the SF [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/create_object.htm) I have created a custom object with the FILES related list.

Using workbench I can successfully see that it receives a message when a new record on that new object is created.

I want to use an an ESB to transfer the new record and the files saved under it to an online cloud storage platfom  (SF>ESB>OnlineCloudStorage)

How do I include the files under that record? so far I only have the fields in the [PUSHTOPIC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/create_a_pushtopic.htm) query.

Answer (score 1):

The files will be associated to the record via a junction object called contentDocumentLink. You will need to query for the files by the linkedEntityId which is the recordId of your custom object record. You could do something like this:

[Select Id, ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId =  : your_custom_record_Id];

Comment: So will this actually transfer the PDF files from Salesforce or will it just stream the object information across?